# Why is the view taking 100% width automatically?

Tags: react-native

I was trying to enclose a View in another View, but the enclosed View was taking 100% of the width even though I hadn't specify it to.

[image]

My main file

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import style from "../styles/screens/RegisterStyle";

export default function SignupRegisterScreen(props) {
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.step}>
        <Text style={style.stepText}>Step-1</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

My styles

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { scaleSize, scaleFont } from "../../theme/Mixins";

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#CBF4E7",
    flex: 1,
  },
  step: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    paddingHorizontal: scaleSize(28),
    paddingVertical: scaleSize(4),
    borderRadius: scaleSize(20),
    marginTop: scaleSize(30),
  },
  stepText: {
    fontSize: scaleFont(16),
    lineHeight: scaleFont(19),
  },
});

export default style;
```

How do I make the view only take the necessary amount of width?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your text. So if you remove the `<Text style={style.stepText}>Step-1</Text>`. The width would set to 0. So the reason why the `Text` component is affecting the width of the parent view is because you didn't specify a height nor a width for the parent View. So react native automatically uses its child containers such as `Text` to fill in its height and width. So, if you increase the font-size of the text, the height of the parent container would increase.